# PyTorch replace torch.nn.Conv2d with torch.nn.functional.conv2d

Tags: pytorch

So I have [this MNIST example](https://github.com/rickiepark/pytorch-examples/blob/master/mnist.ipynb) for PyTorch.
I wanted to replace conv2d with functional method. But got unexpected error.

I replace `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5, padding=2)` with `self.w_conv1 = Variable(torch.randn(1, 32, 5))`

In the forward method I replace `x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), 2)` with `x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(F.conv2d(x, self.w_conv1, padding=2),2))`

And then it will give me an error:

`Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [1, 32, 5], but got input of size [50, 1, 28, 28] instead`

The code worked before, and I thought I'd replace the class with it's functional equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

albanD answerd the question in https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-replace-torch-nn-conv2d-with-torch-nn-functional-conv2d/16596

> Hi,
>
> The error message is not very clear I’m afraid because it comes from
>   deep within the C backend. The problem here is that when you do a
>   convolution on a 2D image with size (batch, in_chan, width, height),
>   and you want an output of size (batch, out_chan, width’, height’),
>   your weights for the convolution should be (out_chan, in_chan,
>   width_kern_size, height_kern_size), basically when you use a kernel
>   size of 5 for the Conv2d function, it is the same as having a kernel
>   of width 5 and height 5. Thus you should have self.w_conv1 =
>   Variable(torch.randn(32, 1, 5, 5)). See the [doc](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) for more details.